# Adding a twig filter to sculpin

Tags: twig, sculpin

I'm trying to use [jasny twig extensions](https://packagist.org/packages/jasny/twig-extensions) with a static [sculpin](http://sculpin.io) site. I added the appropriate line to my `sculpin.json` and ran `sculpin update`. I can see the files have been downloaded in the `.sculpin` folder. Now, how do I enable the twig extension? I know it's not enabled because I get an error if I try to use it and run `sculpin generate`:

```
[ Twig_Error_Syntax: The filter "preg_replace" does not exist in "tech-badges" at line 2 ]
```

Comment: Did you run `sculpin install` prior to `sculpin update?`